# Eigen: periodic view of matrices/vectors

Tags: eigen

I would like to be able to modify the behavior of vectors and matrices when trying to access "out-of-range". For example, this periodic view:

```
Eigen::PeriodicVectorXd x(3);
x.setZeros(); // x = [0,0,0]
x(0)=1; // x=[1,0,0]
x(-1)=-1 // x=[1,0,-1]
x(4)=4  // x=[1,4,-1]
// Also with block operations:
x.segment(2,2)*=2 // x=[2,4,-2]
```

I know this could be done with expressions, but I don't understand the internals that well. Is there another way to achieve this/existing solution?

Comment: You could take the index mod 3. For example, If your index were 5, 5 mod 3 = 2, so 2 would be your index. If your index is -8, -8 mod 3 = 1, so 1 would be your index.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with Eigen. One option would be to subclass Eigen and redefine `operator()`. The bit you'll need is `(n+(i%n)) % n`, where `i` is the index and `n` the size (along the axis of `i`).

Comment: I guess @TomdeGeus suggestion of sub-classing is the most pragmatic solution, if you want that exact behavior. There may be better solutions, e.g., performing the modulo before indexing the matrix (whether that is easier depends on the bigger picture of your actual problem).

Comment: These are good solutions but they don't cover block operations. I edit the question to provide an example.

Comment: What would be the size of your periodic expression? infinite?

Comment: No, not more then the size of the matrix, and typically up to one or two indices outside the range. I just need it to more easily prescribe boundary conditions for pde's, and not make exceptions for the first and last columns.